# AEM -No scrollbar appears in textarea when rendered in HTML view

Tags: adobe, aem, livecycle, livecycle-designer, aem-developer-tools

Is there any settings on how can I show a scrollbar when the text area is rendered in HTML view? I already ticked the **Allow Multiple Lines** in the *Object Pallete*

Comment: Scroll bars are typically rendered by the browser. Modern browser like Chrome and Safari only show a scroll bar if there is too much content to fit in the window. Otherwise they won't show a scroll bar.

Comment: Im using Chrome but still no scrollbar appears

Comment: As I said: They only render a scroll bar if the content does not fit in the box anymore. So add a lot of text and see if the scroll bar appears.